# R Shiny: Fix fluid page column, e.g. to make it immune to scrolling

Tags: r, shiny

my current shiny app works well, but I'm using a fluid page environment as such:

```
    ui.R
    ----
    shinyUI(fluidPage(

     fluidRow(
              column(3,
                     ...long list of inserts...
                    ),

              column(3,
                     ... list of a few insterts...
                    ),

              column(6,
                     ... plot ...
                    )
      ))
```

Now since in the first column there's such a long list of inserts, I'd like to fix the plot output in place, so it scrolls down with the screen.
Any ideas? Is fluid page the wrong environment for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to Shiny/R, but I think you can also use a `fixedPanel` :)
https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/absolutePanel.html

Here's an edited version of mlegge's code that [also works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K2M4.png), using `fixedPanel` :)

```
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
    })
}

long_list <- do.call(tagList, lapply(seq(50), function(ix) {
    id <- paste0("x", ix)
    numericInput(id, id, 1L)
}))

short_list <- do.call(tagList, lapply(seq(10), function(ix) {
    id <- paste0("y", ix)
    numericInput(id, id, 1L)
}))

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(3, long_list),
        column(3, short_list),
        column(6, fixedPanel(top = 10, right = 10, width = "45%", plotOutput("plot")))
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works as well for me, especially with the appropriate setting of width. I could even drop top and right with a very nice auto-configuration for various window sizes. 
It's good to have multiple ways to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bootstrap's `data-spy` directive and `affix` class:

```
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
  })
}

long_list <- do.call(tagList, lapply(seq(50), function(ix) {
  id <- paste0("x", ix)
  numericInput(id, id, 1L)
}))

short_list <- do.call(tagList, lapply(seq(10), function(ix) {
  id <- paste0("y", ix)
  numericInput(id, id, 1L)
}))

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("

     .affix {
        top:50px;
        position:fixed;
      }

    "))
  )

  , fluidRow(
    column(3, long_list),
    column(3, short_list),
    column(6, div(`data-spy`="affix", `data-offset-top`="5", plotOutput("plot")))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]